# Divide long string into multiple strings SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So basically I would like a long string to be cut into smaller pieces, but keeping the words intact. So if I have the following sentence in let's say the FoxTable in the column of JumpColumn:

> the brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and then the lazy dog jumped over the brown fox

I would like to split it into max 20 characters (incl. spaces) in SQL. So the outcome would be something like this:

```
the brown fox jumped 
 over the lazy dog
 and then the lazy 
dog jumped over the 
brown fox
```

However, keep in mind that there are different sentences in the JumpColumn column with different lengths and words.

What my query does now is the breaking it into different lines with a SUBSTRING function in SQL-Server.

```
DECLARE @string_part1 NVARCHAR(500), 
        @string_part2 NVARCHAR(500), 
        @string_part3 NVARCHAR(500), 
        @string_part4 NVARCHAR(500),
        @string_part5 NVARCHAR(500),
        @LoopCount = 1

WHILE (@LoopCount <= 100)
BEGIN
     SELECT
      string_part1 NVARCHAR(500)  = SUBSTRING(JumpColumn, 0, 20)
     ,string_part2 NVARCHAR(500)  = SUBSTRING(JumpColumn, 20, 20)
     ,string_part3 NVARCHAR(500)  = SUBSTRING(JumpColumn, 40, 20)
     ,string_part4 NVARCHAR(500)  = SUBSTRING(JumpColumn, 60, 20)
     ,string_part5 NVARCHAR(500)  = SUBSTRING(JumpColumn, 80, 20)

FROM FoxTable
WHERE Row = @LoopCount

SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
END
```

Comment: I would write a function that puts a ';' (or any other delimiter you want to use) at the end of the word that hits 20 characters and then use string_split to split that across multiple lines

Comment: maybe you can try with a regex CLR then you will have more options to manupulate strings

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
declare @str nvarchar(300) = 'the brown fox jumped  over the lazy dog and then the lazy dog jumped over the brown fox'
declare @finalstring nvarchar(300) =''
while(1=1)
begin


set @finalstring = @finalstring + substring(@str,1,charindex(' ',@str,20)) + ';'
set @str = substring(@str,1+len(substring(@str,1,charindex(' ',@str,20))),len(@str))
if(substring(@str,1,charindex(' ',@str,20)) ='') 
begin
set @finalstring = @finalstring + @str
break
end

end

select ltrim(value) from string_split(@finalstring,';')
```

Not very tidy I know but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from SQL Server 2016 you can use `string_split` to split your sentence into words (before SQL Server 2016 you can use similar functions that you can find on the web):

```
declare @string         nvarchar(max) = 'the brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and then the lazy dog jumped over the brown fox'
declare @tmp            table (row_num int identity(1,1), word nvarchar(20), word_length int)
declare @total          int  
declare @counter        int = 1 
declare @current_lenght int = 0
declare @current_string nvarchar(20) = '' 
declare @next_string    nvarchar(20) = ''
declare @res            table (words nvarchar(20))

insert into @tmp
select value, len(value) 
from string_split(@string, ' ')

select @total = count(*) from @tmp

while @counter <= @total
    begin
        select @next_string = word 
        from @tmp
        where row_num = @counter

        if len(case when @counter = 1 then '' else @current_string + ' ' end + @next_string) > 20
            begin
                insert into @res values (@current_string)
                set @current_string = @next_string
            end
        else
            set @current_string = case when @counter = 1 then '' else @current_string + ' ' end + @next_string
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end
insert into @res values (@current_string)

select * from @res
```

Result:

[image]