# How to get my substr result in multiple lines

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I've a little question.

Here is my query :

```
select * 
  from (select substr(filename,1,30) from reports limit 1,1)query
```

In my reports table I've a row named filename (VARCHAR(300))

I'm looking to select the filename row but in 30 char max

I explain, my filename "a-long-file-name-with-more-30-chars.txt"

In want to 30 first chars in a line "a-long-file-name-with-more-30-" and the rest in another line "chars.txt"

Like this (It's an inspected element)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju477.png

Somethings like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52722082/13304872

Thank you

Comment: Don't do this in sql, formatting should be done in html or php.

Comment: Why do you need that LIMIT 1,1?

Comment: just to select the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to recover the first part

```
select substr(filename,1,30) from reports limit 1,1
```

the second part

```
select substr(filename,31) from reports limit 1,1
```

Comment: Thank you but I would line in 1 request :)
Also in your case if the file have 61 chars it will not working

Comment: the better approach is to write a php code instead of using a unique query

Comment: There is no PHP I'm doing this only with SQL

Comment: to also clip the second part in 30 chracters: select substr(name,31,30) from temp limit 1,1

Comment: try SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    substr(t1.filename,1,30) namet1, 
    t2.id, 
    substr(t2.filename,31,30) namet2
FROM
    temp t1
INNER JOIN temp t2 
 ON t1.id = t2.id;

Comment: I am using temp as the name of the table. You need to create an unique id column in your table to do the join with itself

Comment: the first part will be available at new virtual column namet1 and the second part at namet2

Comment: if you want you can limit the first result SELECT t1.id, SUBSTR( t1.name, 1, 30 ) namet1, t2.id, SUBSTR( t2.name, 31, 30 ) namet2
FROM temp t1
INNER JOIN temp t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LIMIT 0 , 1